# Alternative to HTML Dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm currently having a really long list of university names that are not sorted in alphabetical order. What the user needs to do is quickly find the university's name he/she wants, however the user may or may not know the specific university name, it is requested that the user type one or two keywords and the required university name should appear. Obviously, dropdown wouldn't work out well, what can I do?

EDIT: The user may not know how the university is named, for example the user wants Tokyo University, but in the list, is is "The University of Tokyo", so how do I do so that if the user types in Tokyo University, it will still display "The University of Tokyo" as well (of course, there will be some other university names listed as well...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with using jQuery, the [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) does exactly what you want. You can configure it to use a URL to fetch names as the user types. If the university names are stored in a database, you can write a script to look up all matching names and return them.

Comment: Yeah, I got jQuery and it's stored in the database. So even if the first letter doesn't match the wanted name, it still returns the name?

Comment: @TheOnly92: It depends on how you want it to work. Do you want to match the first letter of any word? In that case, you could have multiple entries in the database for each name, for eg. "University" and "Tokyo" both pointing to the "University of Tokyo" entry.

Comment: No, I want it to work so that "Tokyo" will yield "University of Tokyo".

Comment: @TheOnly92: Yes, that's what I mentioned. You need to structure your database to have word--university name pairs, so that you can have a "Tokyo" word mapping to "University of Tokyo". When you search, you search by the word column and return the matching name columns.

Answer (score 4):

Autocomplete? Similar to google's suggestion stuff? Simple with a bit of Ajax and jQuery.